# Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f6b5d473370>>": "Payment.user" must be a "Account" instance

Tags: python, authentication, django-views, payment-gateway

**views file**

heloo guys i am student learning django i am making a eccomerce website which have paytm payment integration i want to send back payment details to backend but i am getting "Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7f6b5d473370>>": "Payment.user" must be a "Account" instance" error while trying to get user id i dont know whats happening pls help me
i dont why request.user is not working

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import OrderForm
from carts.models import CartItem
import os
from Paytm import Checksum
import datetime
from django.contrib import auth
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from accounts.models import Account
from .models import Order, Payment
MERCHANT_KEY = 'kbzk1DSbJiV_O3p5'

@csrf_exempt
def payments(request,total=0, quantity=0,):
    current_user = request.user
    form =request.POST
    response_dict = {}
    for i in form.keys():
        response_dict[i] = form[i]
        if i == 'CHECKSUMHASH':
            checksum = form[i]

    verify = Checksum.verify_checksum(response_dict, MERCHANT_KEY, checksum)
    pay = Payment()
    if verify:
        pay.payment_id = response_dict['TXNID']
        pay.payment_method = response_dict['PAYMENTMODE']
        pay.user = current_user # this is giving me error
        pay.amount_paid = response_dict['TXNAMOUNT']
        pay.status = response_dict['STATUS']
        pay.created_at = response_dict['TXNDATE']
        pay.save()
        if response_dict['RESPCODE'] == '01':
            print('order succesfull')
        else:
            print('order was not succesfull')
    return render(request,'orders/payments.html', {'response':response_dict})






def place_order(request, total=0, quantity=0,):

    current_user = request.user

    # If the cart count is less than or equal to 0, then redirect back to shop
    cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=current_user)
    cart_count = cart_items.count()
    if cart_count <= 0:
        return redirect('store')

    grand_total = 0
    tax = 0
    for cart_item in cart_items:
        total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
        quantity += cart_item.quantity
    tax = (2 * total)/100
    grand_total = total + tax
    grand_total_paise = (total + tax) * 100

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Store all the billing information inside Order table
            data = Order()
            data.user = current_user
            data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            data.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            data.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            data.address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_1']
            data.address_line_2 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_2']
            data.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
            data.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            data.order_note = form.cleaned_data['order_note']
            data.order_total = grand_total
            data.tax = tax
            data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            data.save()
            # Generate order number
            yr = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y'))
            dt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%d'))
            mt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%m'))
            d = datetime.date(yr,mt,dt)
            current_date = d.strftime("%Y%m%d") #20210305
            order_number = current_date + str(data.id)
            data.order_number = order_number
            data.save()
            Email= data.email

            order = Order.objects.get(user=current_user, is_ordered=False, order_number=order_number)
            param_dict = {
                'MID': 'WorldP64425807474247',
                'ORDER_ID': str(order_number),
                'TXN_AMOUNT': str(grand_total),
                'CUST_ID': data.email,
                'INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID': 'Retail',
                'WEBSITE': 'WEBSTAGING',
                'CHANNEL_ID': 'WEB',
                'CALLBACK_URL':'http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/payments/',

            }
            param_dict['CHECKSUMHASH'] = Checksum.generate_checksum(param_dict, MERCHANT_KEY)
            return render(request, 'orders/payments.html',{'param_dict':param_dict})
    else:
        return redirect('checkout')
```

**Model file**

This is my model file

```
    from django.db import models
from accounts.models import Account
from store.models import Product, Variation
# Create your models here.
class Payment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    amount_paid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.payment_id


class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('New',  'New'),
        ('Accepted','Accepted'),
        ('Completed','Completed'),
        ('Cancelled','Cancelled'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    address_line_1=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order_note = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    order_total = models.FloatField()
    tax = models.FloatField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS, default='New')
    ip = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

    def full_address(self):
        return f'{self.address_line_1} {self.address_line_2}'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    product_price = models.FloatField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.product_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are a newbie and you are out of options. you might want to try logging in or creating the login functionality and then login. after that try doing whatever was generating the error and see how it goes. It solved my problem. DONT TAKE THIS SERIOUSLY.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32629984)